# Is screen sharing possible in cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, webrtc, opentok, screensharing

I am using opentok for video chat and screen sharing. It works perfectly for me on a browser. However my application also run natively using cordova.

There is a cordova-plugin for opentok which supports video calls but not screen sharing.

I want screen sharing to be implemented in my cordova app.

Is it possible? Is it possible using opentok? If not, is it possible using any other alternative?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my research it isn't possible yet with existing plugins to enable screen sharing in a Cordova app.

It is possible to do screen sharing with WebRTC. For example TokBox does have screen sharing implemented in their native SDKs, see:

1. [Android SDK](https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/android/reference/com/opentok/android/Stream.StreamVideoType.html)
2. [IOS SDK](https://tokbox.com/opentok/libraries/client/ios/reference/Constants/OTStreamVideoType.html)

So somebody needs to implement these features into the OpenTok Cordova plugin which is public available to maintain and adjust.

Comment: any update on this?  does the cordova plugin support screen sharing now?

Comment: no the TokBox OpenTok Cordova plugin still doesn't support screen sharing

Comment: Any update on this topic,Now Webrtc supports in Cordova but still not able to share the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Cordova **does not** support *WebRTC* yet. 
There are some plugins which provide WebRTC support as [phoneRTC](http://phonertc.io/).
I think this plugin can help you.

However, instead of Cordova, you can use [Crosswalk](https://crosswalk-project.org/) which support natively WebRTC.

Hope that help.