# Any cordova plugin for screen sharing or support for getDisplayMedia?

Tags: java, android, cordova, android-mediaprojection, get-display-media

Is there any plugin or code that support screen sharing on Android using cordova? Have been searching everywhere but in vain.

Kind of understood we need to use Media Projection but couldn't find a good way to get the video track from the Media Projection API as well as how to request the relevant permission. Looking to build a solution for webrtc.

Please do let me know if there is a solution out there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is screen sharing possible in cordova?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30164337/is-screen-sharing-possible-in-cordova)

Comment: Hi @Eric , no that question doesn't have an answer either. The one marked was not the solution as it is different application. Looking for a cordova plugin in android for sharing the phone screen.